# complete clown show morally speaking, incoherent, arbitrary

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the subject of the sentence "complete clown show morally speaking, incoherent, arbitrary"? If the verb "show" is in a plural form, then the subject should be plural, but "complete clown" is singular.

> Sam Harris (the author of the End of Faith) commented on the following tweet by elizabeth bruenig:
> as a society we have absolutely no coherent story — none whatsoever — about how a person who's done wrong can atone, make amends, and retain some continuity between their life/identity before and after the mistake. **complete clown show morally speaking, incoherent, arbitrary.**

Comment: It's a *tweet*. Why would you expect them to be grammatical? It's not even a sentence! We  capitalise the first letter of a sentence...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this slangy use of ***clown show*** (Google Books doesn't have a single written instance of [**"complete clown show"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22complete+clown+show%22) in all their tens of millions of books) But it looks like a misuse here anyway, in that I assume it's supposed to be describing some activity as being ***incompetently performed*** (which makes little sense when further qualified as being ***morally*** defective in some way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emphasized fragment is not a sentence. The subject is missing. This is very casual writing. It would be more correctly written:

> **It's a** complete clown show ...

Here **it** is the subject and is a placeholder for the topic previously introduced (something like "the situation in today's society").